# Attribute watchers never fire on "native" attributes?

Tags: polymer

In Polymer (0.5.2) it appears that global HTML attributes, like `lang`, cannot be cleanly observed? For instance:

```
<polymer-element name="x-foo" attributes="lang bar">
  ..
  <script>
    Polymer({
        langChanged: function () .. // never fires by itself
        barChanged:  function () .. // fires just fine
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

The interesting part is that the callback does fire if the element is dirtied in other ways. For example:

```
..
ready: function () {
  this.lang = 'en';
}
..
```

This does not trigger any callback. However:

```
..
ready: function () {
  this.lang = 'en';
  this.bar  = 'baz';
}
..
```

This fires both callbacks. So it appears that Polymer isn't correctly being notified about changes to "native" attributes? Is this a known issue? Can this be worked around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The team advises folks to not define properties/attributes that have the same name as native DOM properties/attributes. [link](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#custom-element-prototype-chain)

> Avoid defining a property or method with the same name as a native DOM property or method, such as id, children, focus, title and hidden; the results are unpredictable.

This is because `Object.observe` cannot actually observe those properties. They're coming from the C++ black box inside the browser.

My advice would be to use `language` instead of `lang`.

Comment: That seems to be the case exactly. I thought I skimmed over a statement like that somewhere, but was unable to find it again...

Answer (score 0):

I cant seem to recreate this. What browser are you using?

http://jsfiddle.net/6sqo159z/16/

I had a few similar issues when I used Polymer extensively. Namely on IE.

Are you using the latest version of polymer and platform?
Try giving your attributes default values, even if those values are undefined.
Try including a publish object for your attributes.

```
publish:{
    bar:"",
    lang:""
}
```

Comment: Yup, latest versions in latest Chrome. I tried it pretty much any which way, using published properties, default values, reflected properties, declarative event handler mapping and whatnot.